# Simple error on simple code, but I don't get it?

Tags: java, android

I'm getting this error:

```
Syntax error on token ";", , expected
```

On this very simple code:

```
TextView bio = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.biographyText);

    String bioText = new String();

    bioText = bio.getText().toString();
```

The error is on the semicolon after "new String()"

What's wrong with this? In the end, if someone clicks on the TextView, it'll change the text to whatever they enter.

Here's the whole Java class:

```
public class Profile extends Activity{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


TextView bio = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.biographyText);

String bioText = new String();

bioText = bio.getText().toString();


}
```

Comment: Edited the OP with the whole Java class.

Comment: I'm inclined to suggest that the R.id.biographyText argument is not being handled as expected by your IDE / emulator ? Maybe something wrong with your classpaths / lib associations ? just thinking outloud, i agree that @ first glance nothing other than what i mentioned comes to mind

Comment: That's what's confusing me. The error is talking about that one semicolon, but it's definitely standard code. Nothing too difficult.

@BrandtSolovij I'll clean the project and see if that works.

Comment: Maybe it's just an Eclipse thing? Try closing all your editing files, clean, build...and see if it helps.

Comment: This doesn't help with your problem, but there's no need to assign bioText to a new String before immediately reassigning it to something else.  Instead, simply use: `String bioText = bio.getText().toString();`

Comment: @CarlManaster Thanks, I didn't know that. That fixed it. Want to "Answer" the question so I can set your answer as the right one and give you + rep?

Comment: Close bracket } below super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); is probably a typo.

Comment: The code is going to fail anyway as there needs to be a call to `setContentView(...)` at some point before attempting to use `findViewById(...)`. Those last three lines of code should be inside the `onCreate(...)` method (after a line to set the content view).

Comment: Thanks for the offer, @Cole, but since I don't really think my suggestion affects your problem - you should be able to assign it to a new String, even though it doesn't matter - I don't think my suggestion is the best answer for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip to the last code block for the simple answer

You shouldn't instantiate bioText like that, get rid of

```
new String()
```

and just make it

```
String bioText ="";
bioText = bio.getText().toString();
```

You should never have to instantiate a String by hand, you could instantiate it as "" if you want, but it's not needed. However, to solve your problem, it's simple. The following code must be in a method

```
TextView bio = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.biographyText);
String bioText = "";
bioText = bio.getText().toString();
```

However, this still wont work, seeing as you never call setContentView() in onCreate(). The main problem is the line

```
bioText = bio.getText().toString();
```

You can't instantiate an object, other than where it is declared, outside of a method. To fix this, simple make it

```
String bioText = bio.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even realize I hadn't set the setContentView yet either.